# Aggregating data in 100m*100m blocks on map

Tags: geoprocessing, geoprocessing-service, mgrs

I get customer lat long from an app and my use case is I need to display number of users present in 50m*50m or 100m*100m(deployment time decision) blocks on map.

Some what like below image. No zoom in/zoom out required
[image]

So far I have considered MGRS Id (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system)

But It don't provide me 50m*50m block aggregations.
Can someone please suggest me some algo by which I can do this aggregations.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how it would fare on a huge scale like the whole of the US but if you have a metric (well, cartesian) system QGIS' Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid tool will let you create rectangles. The mmqgis plugin's Create -> Create Grid Lines Layer would be another alternative.

Depending on your extends, your local government might already have a "perfect" grid that you could borrow.

The next step is counting your values per grid cell but that is a trivial GIS operation (Vector -> Analysis -> Points in Polygon in QGIS).